# Xdebug 3 initializes with errors on PHP 8.0

Tags: php, config, xdebug

I can't run Xdebug 3 properly on PHP 8.0. But the same Xdebug config works fine with with PHP 7.3 on the same PC. Also tried changing several ports: no changes. **How to fix Xdebug working with PHP 8.0?**

Main problem described at logs:

```
[Step Debug] Creating socket for '192.168.1.101:10003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).    ⊕
[Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.1.101:10003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
```

- System: Linux Mint 20.3
- PHP: 8.0.29
- Web-server: Apache 2.4.41

Xdebug config:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port=10003
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.scream=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

Xdebug log:

```
[8368] Log opened at 2023-08-06 11:37:58.227380
[8368] [Config] INFO: Systemd Private Temp Directory is enabled (/tmp/systemd-private-7e1a6dcd7e6b41ceb05f74f707b83815-apache2.service-TEbani)
[8368] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:10003.
[8368] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:10003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[8368] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:10003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[8368] Log closed at 2023-08-06 11:37:58.228415
```

Xdebug info page:

[image]

Comment: Please show what Xdebug log shows when it's working (PHP 7.3 as I understand)? Also show the `xdebug_info()` output as well --- so we can compare them. It should show some differences.

Comment: I think you have a few redundant settings (do you want to connect to a specific address or to whoever is making the request?) and you also have directives for Xdebug/2 and Xdebug/3. I'd comment out everything and start by adding the bare minimum settings required (probably just `xdebug.start_with_request` and `xdebug.mode`).